# Diferencias en comandos de git

Tags: git

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre **`git add`** y **`git add --`**.

Después de haberlos probado definitivamente no he encontrado diferencias, pero he visto que unas personas, en algunas ocasiones, usan uno u otro comando, sin embargo no se en que se diferencian realmente.

Comment: Se que el `git add .` añade al índice cualquier fichero nuevo o que haya sido modificado pero NO los ficheros borrados. Pero el `git add--`no me suena para nada

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Los comandos:

```
git add .
```

Al igual que:

```
git add -A
```

Y también como:

```
git add --all
```

> Sirven para indicar que se va a anexar cualquier archivo al stage, desde ese punto estos archivos y sus cambios serán **monitoreados**

De los últimos 2 lo puedes comprobar al ejecutar en cualquier proyecto que este siendo monitorizado por git el siguiente comando:

```
git add --help
```

Que te mostrará entre mas comandos una línea como esta:

> -A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files

**Ahora el comando**

```
git add —
```

De acuerdo a la documentación de git dice

> This option can be used to separate command-line options from the list of files, (useful when filenames might be mistaken for command-line options).

Que se puede traducir como:

> esta opción puede ser usada para separar opciones de línea de comando de la lista de archivos, útil cuando los nombres de los archivos se pueden confundir con las opciones de línea de comandos.

**Referencias**

- [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Answer (score 8):

Bueno según la documentación que se encuentra por internet y la ayuda de los propios comandos en la terminal,

```sh
git add .
```

se usa para agregar los ficheros del directorio actual donde te encuentras a la zona de stage, y si escribe

```sh
 git add --all
```

te servirá igual que poniendo el **punto**.
Por lo menos por lo que yo se por mi propia experiencia y viendo respuestas a preguntas similares a la tuya.
Creo que al final la que te sea más comoda y más rapida.

---

Si te sirve, para más info mira esta respuesta que dan en el stackoverflow en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/26039014/10515716

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia se haría obvia si tuvieras un archivo que se llame como una opción que se le pueda pasar a git.

```
$ touch -- --force # no solo funciona para git el truco de --
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 myself myself 0 Oct 19 19:55 --force
$ git add --force
Nothing specified, nothing added.
hint: Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addEmptyPathspec false"
$ git add -- --force
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   --force
```

La lógica es sencilla.... y aplica para muchos otro comandos, no solo para git. El `--` se utiliza para indicarle a un comando que se acabaron las opciones y lo que viene (normalmente) son nombres de archivos. Por ejemplo:

```
$ echo -n hola
hola$ echo -- -n hola
-- -n hola
$
```